# List of post revisions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, foreign-key-relationship, model-associations

I need help gathering a list of post revisions. Users should be able to see this same list whether on the original post or any following revision of the post. I know that I have to somehow use the foreign key (revision_id) to pull the other revisions when the current post is a revision, but I don't know how.

*Also, if there's a better way to do this, I'm up for the suggestions.*

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    #...
    has_many :revisions, class_name: "Post", foreign_key: "revision_id"
    #...
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
     def show
         @post = Post.find(params[:id])

         if @post.revision_id = nil
             @original = @post
         else
             @original = @post.revision_id
         end

         @revisions = @original.revisions.all
          #...
     end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, `post` can have many `revisions` but `revision` can belong to only one `post`. If so, you don't need `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation and you can use `has_many`/`belongs_to` relations, as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions, class_name: 'Post', foreign_key: 'revised_id'
  belongs_to :revised, class_name: 'Post'
end
```

So now you can do in your controller:

```
if @post.revision_id.nil?
  @original = @post
else
  @original = @post.revised
end

@revisions = @original.revisions
```

or you can move this to model:

```
def original
  revised_id.present? ? revised : self
end
```

and then you can tidy up your controller:

```
@revisions = @post.original.revisions
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks so much. I am curious how I'd filter out such revisions though. Do you have any insight on how I might do this?

Comment: How do you want to filter them? Anyway you can use `scopes` as usual, for example: `@post.original.revisions.your_current_scope`.

Comment: For instance, when creating a new post, you can choose to make it a revision of another post. However, currently it will show all posts which includes posts that are revisions of others. I want to show only the posts that have revisions, but aren't revisions themselves.